# Can I use a port-redirect in Apache as a security layer?

Tags: apache, security, ipython

I'm not an expert web app developer. I have an IPython Notebook server running on some port. The in-built security is not great -- one global password can be set, no support for multiple users or for integrating with (e.g.) active directory or OpenID.

I believe I can use an Apache port redirect to control access. e.g. put a firewall up over the port so external users can't go straight to the notebook, but rather they have to go via port 80 as served by Apache.

Is there some way to write a login page which provides multi-user authentication, then only pass authorised users through to the notebook server?

I apologise in advance if I have used the wrong terminology or glossed over important details.

Comment: Note -- this is an internal application behind the firewall. It doesn't need to be completely unassailable, just provide a reasonable level of security and tracking.

Comment: Possibly Apache in a reverse-proxy configuration could achieve what you want (e.g. requesting individual username and password before serving up the content). Doing a redirect wouldn't accomplish much - the destination address could be shared (or guessed), bypassing the added protection.

Comment: We are building multi-user authentication for IPython as well - it's a separate project called [Jupyterhub](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub), and it does pretty much what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

The apache proxy seems a viable solution (if that meets your needs for login security). You could probably use iptables to do a port forward from that server port (using localhost probably?) to port 80 on apache. This way nobody will be able to access it directly.